# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear el acceso a un sitio web si un usuario accede a ella desde un navegador concreto, como Google Chrome, por ejemplo?

Tags: html5, web, apache

Tengo entendido que si un usuario intenta acceder a un sitio web en concreto, en vez de acceder a ella, aparecería un mensaje diciéndole al usuario que intenta acceder al sitio web usando un navegador en concreto (como Google Chrome), y por lo tanto, el contenido de la web se le bloquea para él, a menos que utilice cualquiera de los navegadores disponibles, menos el que usa (en este caso, Google Chrome).

La intención de esta pregunta es para implementar una versión de mi sitio web imposible de acceder para el usuario que usa un navegador específico, y que en lugar de acceder a esa versión de mi web, se acceda a una versión diferentemente optimizada del mismo o bien bloquearle por completo el acceso hasta que quede lista esa versión especial para ese navegador (Algo similar a lo que ocurría con Internet Explorer y Netscape Navigator). Por lo que necesitaría saber de algún código que tendría que colocar en HTML5, Javascript o HTACCESS para que un navegador en concreto no pueda acceder a mi web hasta nuevo aviso.

De antemano, muchas gracias por sus respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Que tal mauro, podés usar la cabecera UserAgent, que te da ese tipo de datos como sistema operativo, navegador, versión, etc. Y si buscas en developer.mozilla vas a encontrar las cadenas correspondientes para cada navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un htaccess  y en el colocar las líneas, para denegar el acceso a los UserAgent que te interese, como por ejemplo los bots.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(UserAgent1|UserAgent2).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Se pueden poner tantos UserAgent como quieras, separados por **|** 
 aquí tienes un listado de casi todos los useragent disponibles.
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

Comment: Muchas gracias por el dato. Lo voy a intentar y luego comento cómo me fue. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, lo hice así como me dices, pero me sale un error 500, y al revisar el log me sale el mensaje .htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters. ¿Cómo resolver ese problema? Saludos.